# Understanding reference from book.

Tags: reference-request, reference-works

At page 34 of the book The Theory of Matrices (Chelsea Publishing Company), of Cyrus Colton MacDuffee, there is a reference, but I can't understand it. It says:

`KRONECKER: M.-B preuB. Akad. Wiss. 1866 pp. 597-612`

I guess `Akad` and `Wiss` refer to the surnames of some people, but what is `preuB`? I am not able to find to which publication is this referring to.

[image: Here it is like it is showed on the book]

Comment: Abhandlungen der Königlich Preussischen Akademie der Wissenschaften

Comment: @WillJagy: M.-B. = *Monatsberichte*, not *Abhandlungen*. And my German is quite rusty, but shouldn't it be *Königlichen*?

Comment: Not at all names of persons : Akad = Academy, Wiss. = Wissenschaften = Sciences, Preu$\beta$ = Preuss = Prussia. A little context : Prussia was one of the main states of old Germany, around which modern Germany was united in the second half of the 19th century. Its capital was Berlin, explaining that Berlin is (again) the capital city of present-day Germany.

Comment: @HansLundmark  thanks. I assumed M-B  were initials of Kronecker, I could have looked it up.

Comment: @JeanMarie  good. I expect there are Collected Works of Kronecker, not necessarily translated into English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not allowed to write a comment, so I answer here: **preuß. Akad. Wiss.** is the abbreviation of **Preußische Akademie der Wissenschaften** (Prussian Academy of Sciences). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prussian_Academy_of_Sciences.

Answer (score 3):

L. Kronecker, "Über bilineare Formen", *Monatsberichte der Königlich Preußischen Akademie der Wissenschaften zu Berlin*, 1866 (1867), pp. 597–612 ([scan online](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Monatsbericht_der_K%C3%B6niglich_Preussische/yQpUqrq6JXkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA597&printsec=frontcover)).

"ß" is not "B" and not $\beta$, it is a ligature "sz" used in most German-speaking regions with the notable exception of Switzerland, where "ss" is used instead. Prior to 2008, there was no capital "ẞ" version of "ß", so it was rendered as "SS" when writing in uppercase, as on the title page of the publication.

In the reference cited in the question, it occurs in the abbreviation of "preußischen" meaning Prussian. The publication the paper appeared in are the "Monthly Reports of the Royal Prussian Academy of Sciences in Berlin", analogous to the *Proceedings of the Royal Society* (in London). Kronecker read this paper on bilinear forms at the session of October 15, 1866. The annual volume that contains it was published in 1867.

Answer (score 2):

It is a Shortened name of the Journal.

Eg This Doc [[ https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=7e7a26994bd2df73bcbda64550e9d10642dc0646 Page 10 ]] says that :
"Sber. Preuss. Akad. Wiss." indicates "Sitzungsberichte der Preussischen Akademie der Wissenschaften zu Berlin."

Akad == Akademie
Wiss == Wissenschaften

I assume , "Ann. Mat. Pura" indicates "Annals of Pure Mathematics"

The Complication is that , in your Case , the Original is in German.

Your Text Book may have the Shortened names expanded elsewhere.